# Lightbox JavaScript Conflict

Tags: javascript, lightbox

Im developing a HTML scrolling site (its no way near finished) but im having problems with my JavaScript. If I declare the source code before the other the last one works but the first one doesnt.

I have a scrolling JavaScript file that creates a slow scroll effect on navigation click, and the other is a lightbox gallery, the two cannot work in sync and I am really puzzled!

http://www.jn-design.co.uk/Portfolio%20Site/HTML5/#topspace

Comment: Can you please add some more detail? What libraries are you using? Can you show some code? Have you tried using jQuery in No Conflict mode? Thanks.

Comment: Are you making changes to the site you linked to? It appears you're currently trying to implement the suggestion that jassi9911 provided below. That makes it pretty hard for people to troubleshoot your problem...

Comment: Hi sorry guys , im quite a novice when it comes to JQuery , i want to keep the original lightbox i have , i wont be changing it now , i need the two functions to work in sync.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use a simple lightbox gallery rather then some other jQuery plugin. 
For example
http://www.cssjockey.com/web-design-tutorials/an-easy-way-to-create-light-box-with-jquery-css

this is a simple jQuery lightbox it need only a single jQuery plugin that you already used on your website

Comment: so scrap the three lines of code and input this gallery instead?

Comment: i really do not understand how this can be implemented to do what i need it to do , is their no way to use the exsisting slideshow i have>

Comment: just remove all jQuery except 
`http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js`
and follow the instruction of the given link

Comment: the give the demo here 
`http://www.cssjockey.com/files/downloads/code/jquery_css_lightbox/index.htm`

Comment: and they are using id to show lightbox but you have more then one images so you have to give class on each and every images, because id is unique it works only a particular object

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that the actual issue is that jQuery is conflicting with either Prototype or Scriptaculous. I'd recommend running jQuery in [No-Conflict Mode](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/)

Comment: Thanks brian , i am not too sure on how to run this? I am a novice when it comes to JQuery

Comment: @Colin Thanks for the help , i have edited it (locally) if i insert all that code at the top of the head it just clears all my content , if i remove the conflict part only my slideshow functions.

Comment: I have implemented the loading at the top now as suggested , but i still cannot get my lightbox to work , the scroll works , but as soon as positions of declaration sources are swapped it wont work , i understand the concept of the no conflict mode , i just do not understand how to implement it as i am a novice within JQuery?